# Hibernate postCollectionUpdate Trgiigers twice as it removes the existing data and keeps the new one

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

my entities have ManyToMaany relationship

Ex: If my Businessunit class already has 3 user associated after adding a new one it removes old 3 values and adds the new one in to db

and event triggers once for addition and once for removed

and when i remove this listener it works as expected

those Aduditable and AuditableInsert are marker interfaces on which i check if i need to forward the call or not

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@Table(name = "business_unit" ,indexes = {
        @Index(name = "tenantIndx", columnList = "TENANT")
})
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class BusinessUnitJpaEntitiy extends AbstractTenantJpaEntity implements Auditable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1123383144979037984L;

    @Getter
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    String name;
    
    @Getter
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    String description;
    
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "business_unit_user", 
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name ="business_unit_id")}, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="user_id") }
    )
    private Set<User> businessUsers;


    public Set<User> fetchBusinessUsers() {
        return businessUsers;
    }
    
    @Column(name = "DISPLAY_SEQUENCE_NUM")
    protected Long displaySequenceNum;
    
    @Column(name = "UNIQUE_SEQUENCE_ID",unique = true)
    protected String uniqueSequenceId;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "user")
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@ToString(callSuper = true,exclude = {"password"})
public class User extends AbstractTenantJpaEntity implements AuditableInsert{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 65981149772133526L;

    @Getter
    @Column(name = "PROVIDER_USER_ID")
    private String providerUserId;

    @Getter
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "enabled", columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
    private boolean enabled;

    @Column(name = "DISPLAY_NAME")
    private String displayName;

    private String password;

    private String provider;

    @Column(name = "DISPLAY_SEQUENCE_NUM")
    protected Long displaySequenceNum;
    
    @Column(name = "UNIQUE_SEQUENCE_ID",unique = true)
    protected String uniqueSequenceId;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "business_unit_user", 
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name ="user_id")}, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="business_unit_id") }
    )
    Set<BusinessUnitJpaEntitiy> businessUnits;
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        User other = (User) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    
    
}
```

Listener Class

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class BusinessUnitLoggingService implements LoggingService{

    @Autowired 
    private AuditLogSummerizedRepository repo;

    @Override
    public void getMessage(AuditLogSummerizedJpaEntity logSummerizedJpaEntity) {
        logSummerizedJpaEntity.setMessage(StringUtils.capitalize(StringUtils.capitalize(logSummerizedJpaEntity.getRevisionType().name()) +
                " a " + StringUtils.capitalize(logSummerizedJpaEntity.getEntityName()) + " name "
                + logSummerizedJpaEntity.getPropertyName()+" : "+logSummerizedJpaEntity.getState()));
    }


    @Override
    public void logUpdateEvent(PostUpdateEvent event) {
        BusinessUnitJpaEntitiy entity = new BusinessUnitJpaEntitiy();
        try {
            AuditingEntityHolder<BusinessUnitJpaEntitiy> entityHolder = AuditLogUtil.getEntity(event,entity);
            StringBuilder stateBuilder = AuditLogUtil.getLogginDetails(event, entityHolder);
            String propertyName = AuditLogUtil.getName(event);
            AuditLogServiceData modifier = AuditLogUtil.getCurrentModifierDetails();
            AuditLogSummerizedJpaEntity preparedLog = AuditLogUtil.prepareLog(event,modifier, propertyName, stateBuilder);
            getMessage(preparedLog);
            repo.save(preparedLog);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error ocured while careting audit log for "+event.getEntity().getClass() + "  error"+ e);
        }
        
    }
    


    @Override
    public void logCollectionUpdateEvent(PostCollectionUpdateEvent event) {
        try {
        PersistentCollection collection = event.getCollection();
        collection.getOwner();
        String fieldName = collection.getRole().substring(collection.getRole().lastIndexOf(".")+1);
        BusinessUnitJpaEntitiy owner = (BusinessUnitJpaEntitiy) collection.getOwner();
        AuditLogServiceData currentModifierDetails = AuditLogUtil.getCurrentModifierDetails();
        if("businessUsers".equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName)) {
            
            Map storedSnapshot = (HashMap) collection.getStoredSnapshot();
            Set<Object> values = (Set<Object>) collection.getValue();
            
            AuditLogSummerizedJpaEntity auditLogSummerizedJpaEntity = AuditLogSummerizedJpaEntity.builder()
                                                                                                    .revisionType(AuditLogEventsEnum.UPDATED)
                                                                                                    .entityName(AuditLogUtil.sanitizeEntityName(owner.getClass().getSimpleName()))
                                                                                                    .propertyName(owner.getName())
                                                                                                    .entityId(owner.getId())
                                                                                                    .user(currentModifierDetails.getCurrentUser())
                                                                                                    .businessUnitId(currentModifierDetails.getBusinessUnitId())
                                                                                                    .tenant(currentModifierDetails.getTenant())
                                                                                                    .state(AuditLogUtil.getObjectState(fieldName, storedSnapshot, values))
                                                                                                    .build();
            getMessage(auditLogSummerizedJpaEntity);
            repo.save(auditLogSummerizedJpaEntity);
        }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error occured : "+e);
        }
    }

}
```

Listener registration

```
public class HibernateListener {

    private final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired
    private EntityUpdateListener updateListener;
    
    @Autowired
    private CollectionUpdateListener collectionUpdateListener;
    
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class);
        EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_UPDATE).appendListener(updateListener);
registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_COLLECTION_UPDATE).appendListener(collectionUpdateListener);
    }
```

message generation logic

```
public static String getObjectState(String fieldName, Map storedSnapshot, Set<Object> values) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        Collection<Object> oldValues = storedSnapshot.values();
        if(oldValues.size() > values.size()) {
            oldValues.removeAll(values);
            for(Object value : oldValues) {
                    builder.append(" Removed: "+fieldName+" : ");
                    builder.append(AuditLogUtil.getMappingEntity(value));
            }
            
        }else if(oldValues.size() < values.size()) {
            values.removeAll(oldValues);
            for(Object value : values) {
                    builder.append(" Added: " + fieldName + " : ");
                    builder.append(AuditLogUtil.getMappingEntity(value));
            }
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

issue was with   oldValues.removeAll(values);

here we remove the list before transaction is completed hence any modification to this will create a new db opearaation